# Printing Time without leading zero in Javascript

Tags: javascript, string, time, format

I'm pretty sure this is simple but I am trying to print out the current time in 12-hour format without including the leading zero in the time string. So, for example.

09:30 AM should print as 9:30 AM.

The current code I have so far (which prints the version with the leading zero) is this:

```
var d = new Date();
var timeString = d.toLocaleTimeString([], {hour: '2-digit', minute:'2-digit'});
```

How can I change the above code to remove the leading zeros when they appear?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use the `numeric` format for the hour instead of `2-digit`

```js
var timeString = d.toLocaleTimeString([], {hour: 'numeric', minute:'2-digit'});
```

---

```js
const d = new Date();
d.setHours(9, 30);

console.log(d.toLocaleTimeString([], {hour: '2-digit', minute:'2-digit'}));
console.log(d.toLocaleTimeString([], {hour: 'numeric', minute:'2-digit'}));
```

Answer (score 1):

Your code is specifying:

```
hour: '2-digit'
```

Just get rid of that and all is well.  :-)

For the US locale, here's what I get:

```
const d = new Date();
console.log(
  d.toLocaleTimeString() // 8:40:28 PM
);
```

See also:  https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date/toLocaleTimeString#using_options

Comment: Thank you for the reference link. This will be useful for the future